# Recyclerview overflowing ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a recyclerview that grows in size with additional items until a certain max height and then fades away. I understand that Constraint layout is the right way to go here and I swear this was already working a month or so ago and then the Recyclerview stopped caring about its constraint and being visible beyond 280dp (see picture). here is my code. I am certain this was already working, I dont know if google changed something to implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4" or if I am slowly going mad. Maybe someone knows how to fix this. maybe its down to the implementation being beta. any help will be much appreciated.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_tilemap"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="280dp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rv_comms"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: how actually you want your layout should like?

Comment: in the image above you can see a fading edge on the last item. the issue is that the item continues being visible beyond that fading edge. as you can see it is overlapping with my compass it should in fact cease being visible just above the compass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the culpable code. turns out the recording buttons in my adapter are to blame. they included the following method that enabled the button to overflow the views of other adapter items (when pressed the button will grow like in whatsapp, see image bellow)

```
public void setClip(View v) {
    if (v.getParent() == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) v).setClipChildren(false);
        ((ViewGroup) v).setClipToPadding(false);
    }

    if (v.getParent() instanceof View) {//this part is to blame
        setClip((View) v.getParent());
    }
}
```

the recursive nature of the method (seen already commented out in the last 4 lines of the method) basically set clipToPadding and clipChildren to false for the entire hierarchy of views from the record button upwards wich lead to the weird overflow. I ended up manually setting clipToPadding and clipChildren to false for only those views that were concerned with the adapter (this allowed me to retain the cool recording button overflow animation without having the fading edge issue) and now it looks pretty (see below).

[image: this is what I was going for]